# Need help decompressing GIF raster data

Tags: gif, compression, lzw

I have a 10x10 gif that consists of 4 colors, white, red, blue, black. I have parsed the gif data below

```
4749 4638 3961                      <-- header

0a00 0a00 9100 00                   <-- lsd (pb 91 = 1001 0001) nColors = 4, bytes = 12

ffffff ff0000 0000ff 000000         <-- global color table
                                    #0  FF FF FF
                                    #1  FF 00 00
                                    #2  00 00 FF
                                    #3  00 00 00

21f9 04(00) (0000) (00)00           <-- graphics control extension 
                                    (00) = pb (000 reserved 000 disposal method 0 user input flag 0 transparent color flag) 
                                    (0000) = delay time                     
                                    (00) = transparent color index

2c 0000 0000 0a00 0a00 00           <-- image descriptor

02 16                               <-- (image data - 02 = lzw min code size, 0x16 size of image (bytes))
8c2d 9987 2a1c dc33 a002 75ec 95fa a8de 608c 0491 4c01 00   <-- image block
3b
```

Okay so we have our image data above (labeled image block) and I'm trying to decompress this so that I get the original image back. My understanding is that you read bytes left to right and bits right to left starting with lzwmincodesize + 1 (2 + 1 bits = 3 bits at a time).

This is the decompression algorithm I'm following

```
Initialize code table
let CODE be the first code in the code stream
output {CODE} to index stream
<LOOP POINT>
let CODE be the next code in the code stream
is CODE in the code table?
Yes:
    output {CODE} to index stream
    let K be the first index in {CODE}
    add {CODE-1}+K to the code table
No:
    let K be the first index of {CODE-1}
    output {CODE-1}+K to index stream
    add {CODE-1}+K to code table
return to LOOP POINT
```

I'm stepping through the decompression algorithm and here's what I've come up with so far... (starting with first 3 byte codes)

```
Global Color Table
000 FF FF FF
001 FF 00 00
010 00 00 FF
011 00 00 00
100 CLEAR
101 End of Data

 3  2   1   6  5   4      8   7    
10|001|100  0|010|110|1  100|110|01

last        current     output      cindex      exists      dictionary      value
            100                     4                                       CLEAR
100         001         001         1           y                           RED
001         110         001 001     6           n           +001 001        RED RED
001 001     110         001 001     6           y           +001 001 001    RED RED
001 001     010         010         2           y           +001 001 010    BLUE
010         010         010         2           y           +010 010        BLUE
010         110         001 001     6           y           +010 001 001    RED RED
001 001     100                     4                                       CLEAR
100         111         111         7 ???? <--- (what do I do here)?
```

I should be getting 5 values of red, and then 5 values of blue for the first 10 pixels but as you can see it decodes 5 red then 2 blue then 2 red. Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake comes from missing the code size increase. Here are the codes, "nextcode" values and current code size:

```
Code read from bitstream:    100, 001, 110, 110, 0010, 1001
internal 'Next' code value:  110, 110, 110, 111, 1000, 1001
current code size:             3,   3,   3,   3,    4,    4
```

The missing logic from your decode loop is that you need to maintain a "nextcode" variable which tells you where to insert codes in your table and when to increase the code size. It starts at the value "clearcode + 2" and increases after each code is read from the bitstream (after the first non CC value).  The logic basically looks like this:

```
clear_dictionary:
clearcode = 1<<codestart;
codesize = codestart+1;
nextcode = clearcode + 2;
nextlimit = 1<<(codesize+1);
oldcode = -1;
mainloop:
while (!done)
{
code = getCode();
if (code == clearcode)
   goto clear_dictionary;
if (oldcode == -1)
{
   write_code_to_output(code);
}
else
{
   <LZW logic>
   nextcode++;
   if (nextcode >= nextlimit)
   {
      nextlimit <<= 1;
      codesize++;
   }
}
oldcode = code;
} // while !done
```

Comment: how did you maintain the next code in this? my next code stream comes out like this? 110 110 010 010 110 100 111

Comment: For each code that's not a clear code and not the first code after a cc, you increment the "nextcode" variable.

Comment: Ok so here's the code stream 10001100  00101101  10011001  10000111. Here is how the next code variable lines up for me for each code thats not cc and not first code after cc.

read code: 100 001 110 110 010 100 (cc read and 111 is next code)
next code: 110 110 010 010 110 111 (which you say to skip)

if i try to follow this with my algorithm its output is not correct still.

Comment: The "nextcode" always increments; it is an internal variable, not the code read from the bitstream.